# What solutes will give the largest reduction in volume when dissolved in water

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, solutions

This question is inspired by [another question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31249/the-magical-water-drum).

If you take some common salt (NaCl) and some water and mix them, then the volume of the solution is less than the volume of the constituents.

I did some calculations with;

- 5.75 L salt
- 44.25 L water
- total initial volume 50 L

Density of salt is 2.170 kg/L so resulting solution is 22% concentration, which has a density of 1.164 kg/L. Therefore resulting volume is 48.73 L. This means the solution has a volume 1.27 L lower than the constituents.

My question is in two parts;

1. Are my calculations correct?
2. Is there another solute that would give a solution with volume 4 L lower than the constituents, given the volume of the constituents must be 50 L.

Comment: If you consider all kinds of solutes, “the largest reduction in volume when dissolved in water” applies to _gases_ such as $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{SO2}$, $\ce{HCl}$, or $\ce{NH3}$ (see also _fountain experiment_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Your calculations are correct.

(2) $\ce{CaCl2}$ has a density of 2.16 kg/L

```
           kg        vol(L)
  CaCl2    18.00     8.38
  H2O      41.62    41.62
           -----    -----
           59.62    50.00 L
```

But when dissolved the solution has a density of 1.300 kg/L, so the total volume is 45.86 L. ([Data about $\ce{CaCl2}$ solutions.](http://www.oxy.com/OurBusinesses/Chemicals/Products/Documents/CalciumChloride/173-01791.pdf))