# What is the highest volume change for common miscible liquid pairs, and common solvent/solid pairs?

Tags: solvents

When a solute is added to a solvent, the total volume of the solution is lower than that of the solute+solvent. A good example of this is the addition of salt to water, causing an overall volume decrease. What are the most dramatic example of this for commonly available solvents and solutes, both liquid+solid, and liquid+liquid?

Comment: Interesting question. My guess is the best examples will be pairs where mixing "turns on" some very strong intermolecular interaction which is not present in either compound separately. For example, choose a strong donor but weak acceptor of hydrogen bonds, and mix it with a strong acceptor but weak donor of hydrogen bonds. Maybe something like [hexafluoroisopropanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexafluoro-2-propanol) and [hexamethylphosphoramide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexamethylphosphoramide).

Comment: What are the dramatic examples, to find the most dramatic one?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49913/what-solutes-will-give-the-largest-reduction-in-volume-when-dissolved-in-water https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23534/how-does-volume-contraction-in-solvent-mixing-work

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/167434/why-is-there-a-decrease-in-the-total-volume-when-naoh-dissolves-in-water https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83765/is-it-possible-to-have-volumesolution-volumesolvent-before-adding-solute

Comment: lower alcohols and water give ~10% decrease, if I remember correctly. In a plastic container, *filled* 50/50 with alcohol *carefully* floated atop water (might need a plastic-wrap separator), the container should get squeezed in the middle when shaken.